# Can I take an aerial photography drone on a plane as carry-on?

Tags: equipment-protection, travel, aerial-photography

I live in US and thinking to travel to Europe next spring. I'm thinking to get a drone with couple extra batteries and take it with me as a carry on to get some aerial shots. Anybody had any experience with that? For example, I'm thinking about the DJI Phantom or Inspire; are 5200mAh (57.72Wh) and (129.96Wh) respectively.

Comment: This is not about photography.

Comment: You might also want to check and find out if flying them is legal in the jurisdictions you are visiting...

Comment: Better here:  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-luggage

Comment: Batteries with that kind of capacity will most likely need to be in your checked luggage. I have no idea about the drone itself. How do the drone's dimensions compare to the airline's published maximum carry on dimensions? This varies from one airline to the next, and sometimes from one type of equipment (plane type) to the next within the same airline.

Comment: @shershams, maybe you **can** take it on a plane, but **you won't be allowed to use it in France**... (and not about photography)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The regulations are a bit odd, but as you are travelling to Europe, I will refer you to the UK regs:

http://www.britishairways.com/cms/global/pdfs/lithium_battery.pdf

In essence you need to declare anything over 100Wh and cannot transport anything over 160Wh

You cannot put spare packs in the hold, if you put the copter in the hold with a pack attached that is OK. The rest must be in carry-on.